# Public Available Function in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

If I would like to make a function in Laravel, that is available everywhere in my app, how would I go about that?

What I mean, is that, if I create a function called resizeimage() and would like to call it from anywhere in my Laravel application, how can I do this?

Comment: I would recommend adding your functions to the Laravel `helpers.php` file. Nonetheless, it would be better to create packages with Facades for your utility functions - PHP is headin in this direction anyway. See http://laravel.com/docs/packages and http://laravel.com/docs/facades for more information.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, thank you ^^ I can't seem to find the "helpers.php", where should it be located?

Comment: @MikeAnthony That's a file inside the framework itself, under vendor folder. You really shouldn't edit that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a folder named: `libraries`

Create a file(class) in your library: `Image.php`

Then add this code to `Image.php`:

```
<?php

class Image{

   public static function resizeImage($image){
      return $image;
   }

}
```

Edit `global.php` in your 'start'-folder: Add `app_path().'/libraries',`

Example:

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(

    app_path().'/commands',
    app_path().'/controllers',
    app_path().'/models',
    app_path().'/database/seeds',
    app_path().'/libraries',

));
```

Now you can call your 'function' like this 'anywhere':

```
Image::resizeImage('http://path/to/image');
```

Answer (score 3):

You could create a **helpers.php** file inside **app** and require it on **app/start/global.php**.

**app/helpers.php**

```
<?php

    function resizeimage() {
        // resize image
    }
```

**app/start/global.php**

```
// ...
// At the bottom

require app_path().'/helpers.php';
```