# Laravel 4 - Accessing Folders

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am new to Laravel 4, and I come from a Zend Framework background. I'd like to create a folder `app/forms` and keep all my forms there. How can I refer to the form in the `controller` and within the `view.blade` files?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the root of the view files folder is `app/views` so if you create a folder in `views` like `app/views/forms` then you may refer the form by it's name from a controller like:

```
$form = View::make('forms.formfile');
```

Here, formfile is the name of the file that contains the form and it could be `formfile.blade.php` and to refer/include the form file from a view you may use `@include`:

```
// In a blade view file
@include('forms.form1')
```

Assume that, `form1` is a blade view inside the `forms` folder and saved as `form1.blade.php`, you may also use sub-folders inside the `forms` folder, for example in `views/forms/user` folder you may keep a view named `index.blade.php` and use it like:

```
// From a controller
$userForm = View::make('forms/user/index');
```

From a `view` file: (folders are separated by `.`)

```
@include('forms.user.index') // file: app/views/forms/user/index.blade.php
```

You can also nest views in the controller, check [the manual](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#views) for more.

Comment: Yes, I know I can do that. I wanted to keep forms in the route directory. Is that a bad practice? This might be because this is how ZF does it! You keep the forms in the route directory!

Comment: You should never place such things in your routes file

Comment: You can put it in your preferred folder but it's not good as Jazerix said but you may change the place or add another place in the `app/config/view.php`.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at this question, i asked some time ago. With this you can create your own files that will be loaded :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706641/public-available-function-in-laravel-4

Comment: Another idea would be to look at laravels HTML macros. There you can create own forms or even combinations of elements and just call your macro as if it was any ither HTML function in laravel http://laravel.com/docs/html#custom-macros

Answer (score 0):

From the standpoint of Laravel, HTML forms (and all presentation related  things ) belongs to **app/views/** folder. Exceptions are package specific views. For example some commands has their own stubs and views and they are usually stored inside package.
Laravel is very flexibile, and you can move things around and create new folders and namespaces. You just have to tell **composer** that you are changing Laravel default structure, and **dumpautoload**. That is if you only want to create new folder with internal reference. If you want something with more scope and visibility you'll have to bind that to container, so that will be visible inside whole application.

You are coming from the Zend world, so I can understand that you want to move some of Zend "flavour" to Laravel. Although is it possible, I would really recommend you to take some time and learn how Laravel works. There are some great ideas and design inside. Of course, Zend has its own quality, but hey - this is Laravel :)